# Install and compile irrlicht on windows (CLION)

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, cross-platform, irrlicht

I'm a student developer and I've always dev on Linux. This is the first project I have to do crossplateform. So I installed Git Bash, Visual Studio Pro and CLion on Windows. Usually I compile with GCC and Makefiles. So on Linux I installed the lib run the examples of the lib and it work. But when I want to compile it on Windows, it gets complicated.

I use the example files given by Irrlicht to make sure it doesn't come from the sources.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(bomberman)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

find_package(Irrlicht)


link_libraries(Irrlicht)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
        "/usr/include/irrlicht"
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
include_directories(inc)

add_executable(bomberman
 src/main.cpp)
```

I didn't install Irrlicht on Windows because I don't know how to do it. So, I tried many things and look around the Internet, actually I add:

- Irrlicht.exp
- Irrlicht.lib

And I put it at the root of the project but I don't know where to put all the lib with the H points. And I don't know how to optimize CROSSPLATEFORM. If anyone has tips, tuto, advice I'm really into.

Thank you in advance the community.

Comment: ***/usr/include/irrlicht*** On windows??

Comment: no just on linux I actually add this if else

Answer (score 0):

Your CMakeList doesn't have to work on windows you just have to provide an .exe installer that install the project on the server.

This is my interpretation of the indie_studio subject:

> You MUST use CMake <s>as a cross-platform build system</s> (*it just cmake description not a requirement*):
>
> •Linux: the Makefile generated by cmake must have an install target which will install the required libraries and the game on the system.
>
> •Windows: **you must provide an executable installer file**.
>   Various programs let you easily create an installer.

good luck :)