# Build error LNK1104 for CMake project using Irrlicht

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, irrlicht

I'm currently working on a school project with Visual Studio 2019, and we face a problem:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Irrlicht.lib'
```

The error only came when we already have compiled our CMake file, the first time it's working.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(IndieCMAKE)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

find_package(Irrlicht)

link_libraries(Irrlicht)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
        "/usr/include/irrlicht"
        "./include"
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
include_directories(inc)

add_executable(IndieCMAKE
 ./main.cpp)
```

Here is my `FindIrrlicht.cmake` file:

```
    IF (NOT Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS OR NOT Irrlicht_LIBRARIES)
  FIND_PATH(Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS
    NAMES
      irrlicht.h
    PATHS
      /usr/include/irrlicht/        # Default Fedora28 system include path
      /usr/local/include/irrlicht/  # Default Fedora28 local include path
      ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/include/ # Expected to contain the path to this file for Windows10
      ${Irrlicht_DIR}/include/      # Irrlicht root directory (if provided)
  )

  IF (MSVC)     # Windows
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "")
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib")
  ELSE (MSVC)   # Linux
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "lib")
    SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so")
  ENDIF(MSVC)

  FIND_LIBRARY(Irrlicht_LIBRARIES
    NAMES
      Irrlicht
    PATHS
      /usr/lib64             # Default Fedora28 library path
      /usr/lib/                     # Some more Linux library path
      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/    # Some more Linux library path
      /usr/local/lib/               # Some more Linux library path
      /usr/local/lib64/             # Some more Linux library path
      ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/         # Expected to contain the path to this file for Windows10
      ${Irrlicht_DIR}/              # Irrlicht root directory (if provided)
  )
ENDIF (NOT Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS OR NOT Irrlicht_LIBRARIES)

IF (Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS AND Irrlicht_LIBRARIES)
  SET(Irrlicht_FOUND TRUE)
ELSE (Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS AND Irrlicht_LIBRARIES)
  SET(Irrlicht_FOUND FALSE)
ENDIF (Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS AND Irrlicht_LIBRARIES)

IF (Irrlicht_FIND_REQUIRED AND NOT Irrlicht_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR
    "  Irrlicht not found.\n"
    "      Windows: Fill CMake variable CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to the provided directory.\n"
    "      Linux: Install Irrlicht using your package manager ($> sudo dnf install irrlicht-devel).\n"
  )
ENDIF (Irrlicht_FIND_REQUIRED AND NOT Irrlicht_FOUND)
```

Here are my CMake GUI variables:

[image: cmake log]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the responses to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/3987854) question for how to properly *link* a library to your executable. Your code looks strangely similar to the code posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279559/install-and-compile-irrlicht-on-windows-clion) question. Note, you should modify the paths to match *your* system, instead of using Unix-style paths, which are likely not relevant on Windows...

Comment: Please provide the CMake *output* in your question post. Does CMake even successfully find Irrlicht (via the `find_package()` call)? It would seem you may need to use your own custom FindIrrlicht.cmake file as suggested in this [thread](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=37091).

Comment: I have my own FindIrrlicht.cmake that find my lib the first time

Comment: i provide the cmake output

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CMake [Find Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules), such as a `FindIrrlicht.cmake` file, the `find_package(Irrlicht)` command should populate some `Irrlicht_*` CMake variables for you. Assuming `find_package()` actually found the package components correctly, you can use these `Irrlicht_*` variables in your CMake file to specify where CMake should look for Irrlicht package headers and libraries.

Something like the following CMake file should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(IndieCMAKE)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Use REQUIRED here, to ensure CMake finds the package before continuing.
find_package(Irrlicht REQUIRED)

# Don't use this command. It's old, and the syntax didn't work, in your case.
#link_libraries(Irrlicht)

# Specify your directories that contain headers, including the Irrlicht headers.
include_directories(
    ${Irrlicht_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Define your executable target.
add_executable(IndieCMAKE
    main.cpp
)

# Link the Irrlicht library to your executable target.
target_link_libraries(IndieCMAKE PRIVATE ${Irrlicht_LIBRARIES})
```